# Why is baidu.com inaccessible from my iPhone browser if I have “Prevent Cross-Site Tracking” turned on?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, mobile-safari

Since 2018 or so, I have noticed that my iPhone (12 to now 14) has been unable to access baidu.com, on both the Safari and Chrome browser.

I had previously deleted cookies but saw the same thing, “Safari can’t open the page because the server can’t be found”. Today I toggled several buttons on and off in Safari settings and noticed that once I turned off “Prevent Cross-Site Tracking”, I could suddenly access baidu.com again. The strange thing is, I previously could access ir.baidu.com, research.baidu.com, and other subdomains, but not the search engine baidu.com.

I was wondering if there might be an explanation for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, Baidu is using this feature. I think it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is baidu.com inaccessible from my iPhone browser if I have “Prevent Cross-Site Tracking” turned on?

It’s not your browser (Chrome or Safari) that’s being blocked, it’s the content that baidu.com is pulling from that is being denied.

There’s very little on the baidu homepage except for a bunch of Javascript that pulls content from elsewhere an a ton of trackers.  Let’s just say that baidu.com is a central connection point for cross-site scripting and tracking.  When you enable cross-site tracking prevention, it breaks their functionality.

In the end, this isn’t an Apple, iPhone your browser or anything to do with the device in your possession. This has to do with baidu.com wanting to access all of your browser data.